# Why isn't TextOverflow.Ellipsis working as intended with my Text Widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use TextOverflow.Ellipsis to make sure some text data doesn't cause an overflow error. Only problem is that it doesn't seem to be working properly for me. I add the property but the text doesn't get shortened and still causes an overflow error. Anyone got an idea of why this is occurring and how to fix it?

This is how it currently looks. Even with Ellipsis added.

[image]

This is the code that renders it all.

```
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 3,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13, left: 10),
                                        child: Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(mileage[index].trippurpose,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 15,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                softWrap: false,
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                          ],
                                        )),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            '${mileage[index].tripfrom} - ',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 36),
                                            child: Text(
                                              mileage[index].tripto,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),),
```

Comment: minor changes inside your ```Row()``` just wrap your ```Text``` widget with ```Expanded``` parent widget

Comment: Worked like a dream for the first line. Didn't seem to do much for the second line though. I applied it to the mileage[index].tripto Text as that is where I think it would start to overflow for that row, and it still says its overflowing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would always add the `maxLines: 1` property to the `Text` widget in this kind of layouts.

Then...

- If you can, try removing the `Row` widget.
- If you can't remove the `Row` widget, wrap the `Row` widget with the `Expanded` widget around.